# Should abbreviation be written in small caps or in lower case?

Tags: discussion

It is agreed that only proper nouns and sentences begins should use capital letters.
Small caps have the same case as lower case letters which still mark the difference that the word *(if it is for only one word)* isn’t common noun or verb or adjective.

Despite universal character set transformation format 8 bits is the by specs the default character encoding for hypertext transfer protocol *(and that page is served as universal character set transformation format 8 bits)*, it seems the community consensus is to use only what search engine handle natively *(numbers and lower case letters)*

Comment: You are being needlessly argumentative. Please take a breath and re-consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since writing (especially here) is primarily about **communication**, you should do everything in your power to enhance communication, with as many of our users as possible.

Just as you wouldnt write here in grammatically correct French, you shouldn't use any non-standard or non-common forms.

Why would you go out of your way to obfuscate your communications?

Comment: Ah bon ? Et pourquoi pas ? Et du français grammatical incorrecte, je peut ?

Comment: @Gilles I have no idea if that is grammatically correct - so joke's on me! Wait...

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is generally agreed that [acronyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym) are written in uppercase. While some styles use small caps for acronyms, this is rare.

In any case, Stack Exchange does not have small caps [formatting](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so the question is moot.

Unicode has some characters that look like Latin small caps letters, but their semantics is *not* small caps, only their visual appearance. (They're mostly phonetic symbols.) Since their semantics is not that of letters, they should not be used to represent letters, otherwise a lot of software will interpret them incorrectly (e.g. when searching text). Furthermore many fonts lack some or all of those characters, which are rarely used.

Please do what everybody else does, which is to use uppercase for acronyms.

Comment: You’re speaking about french here …

Comment: @user2284570 No, I'm speaking about English. French actually has a slightly higher tendency to use small caps for acronyms, but it's still a minority usage.

Comment: Which [might change in the future](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/Outils/Xorg‐fr/).

Answer (score 6):

For Stack Exchange, I'd suggest never using small caps, or any Unicode chars that aren't standard, for a couple of reasons:

- It makes it very difficult to read — many people don't have wide sets of fonts.
- Search engines will not necessarily handle things gracefully.
- It isn't the way things are done in normal English - we generally abbreviate using upper case (assuming you're talking about acronyms).

Comment: Small caps are standard.`search engines will not necessarily handle things gracefully` *(they handle it like upper case by converting to their lower case equivalents)*. I’ll just wait for other answers before considering accepting that one.

Comment: From my perspective, the other two are most important. If people can't read your posts, you won't get good answers, and we are all about good answers.

Comment: Yes, and that kind of peoples who don’t browse the web with required specifications are likely to get other problems. This isn’t like JavaScript or Flash Player *(I know Flash isn’t standard)*.